# Use functions from base class as templates inside derived class

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my usecase:

```
class A:
protected: 
   virtual void methodA1(const void* const s, const std::streamsize n) const;
   inline void methodA2(const void* const s, const std::streamsize n) const;

class B : public A
private:
    const  char *a;
    template <void (*T)(const void* const, const std::streamsize)>
    void doOperation(const char* b) {        
        T(a, b - a);
    }

    //here comes the template usage
    void methodB1(const char *x) {
         doOperation<methodA1>(x);
    }

    void methodB2(const char *x) {
         doOperation<methodA2>(x);
    }
```

The problem is that will not compile. I get error like `template argument deduction/substitution failed:` and `invalid use of non-static member function`.

How could I achieve the desired behaviour ?

Comment: Please post real code, the syntax is totally wrong here. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: You also didn't say what "desired behaviour" is

Comment: Why use a template for this?

Comment: Because `methodB1` and `methodB2` contain the same code except for the call of either `methodA1` either `methodA2`

Comment: @cehptr That could be done with a normal function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`methodA1` is of type `void (A::*)(const void* s, std::streamsize) const`.

So you have to adjust your code to something like:

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void methodA1(const void* const s, const std::streamsize n) const = 0;
   void methodA2(const void* const s, const std::streamsize n) const {}
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    const  char *a;
    void methodA1(const void* s, std::streamsize n) const override {}

    template <void (A::*M)(const void*, std::streamsize) const>
    void doOperation(const char* b) {        
        (this->*M)(a, b - a); // method pointer usage
    }

    //here comes the template usage
    void methodB1(const char *x) {
         doOperation<&A::methodA1>(x);
    }

    void methodB2(const char *x) {
         doOperation<&A::methodA2>(x);
    }
};
```